# How to make multiple calendars in Windows Calendar

Tags: windows, windows-10, calendar, windows-10-calendar-app

I'm using Windows 10 and trying to make multiple calendars in the built-in app.
I don't want more Microsoft accounts to manage.
I just want the functionality that you get with multiple accounts in my one account, those functions are;

1. The ability to hide or show each calendar using the check box
2. The ability to add events to each calendar individually
3. Ideally the ability to add multiple events at once though that may be asking for Windows to be actually useful which is clearly not on their agenda.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but this article explains how to create additional calendars.
[Create additional calendars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-additional-calendars-4b5570c4-e95d-4673-b38a-2b8ead5f00ee)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I saw this before making my post. This is for Outllook 2016 which is not Windows 10 calendars app.